# Assigning a dynamic path to file upload in php

Tags: php, upload

i have got a class which is used to upload a file checking its size etc, now i want that the path that i give to save the uploaded file should be dynamic like for example:if i am uploading some documents to leads in  crm project than the path should be set in such a way that what ever i upload there should go to that leads folder.and so on for other folder depending upon where i am uploading
is this possible. currently m assigning a static path from my html form

Comment: `if` statements and appropriate `move_uploaded_file()` calls? Or am I missing something here...

Comment: @ Andrew Moore Actually, the path should be dynamically created depending upon the form which user is using to upload for ex: if user is uploading files in page1 then the files should be uploaded to page1's folder and soon,but there will be only one backend file for all the file uploads in all pages where there is an upload

Answer (score -1):

HTML part

```
<input type="hidden" name="filetype" value="crm">
```

PHP part

```
if($_POST['filetype'] === "crm") $path="crm";
```

You can use that technique not only for the file manipulations but for SQL, draw a graphics, display stock exchange etc.
It is called "programming".

Comment: how will it get
 to CRM folder, how does it trace the path?

Comment: @mayuri notice  `$path="crm";` part. you can put here any path you desire instead of `crm` one. Btw, do you have any programming/PHP experience? At least to read code snippets?

Comment: @mayuri I havent seen where you stated it. Anyway I don't accuse you. Just asking to see what level of assistance you need.